# RuntimeException when loading image from device and applying parallax effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-xml

In my app i want to load an image from gallery  or take an image using camera and i want to apply parallax scrollview effect on that image.I have an xml file called header ,it contains an image view and two buttons,one for loading image another one for taking image using camera.I tried this code but app crashes when i run the app ,it shows Runtime exception in the logcat,can anybody help me to find out the problem??

Logcat

```
06-03 12:39:02.683  27327-27327/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.zoid.parallaxtutorial/in.zoid.parallaxtutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at in.zoid.parallaxtutorial.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

```
MainActivity.java


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int lastTop = 0;
//ImageView image;
ListView listView;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

public void parallax(final View v) {
    final Rect r = new Rect();
    v.getLocalVisibleRect(r);

    if (lastTop != r.top) {
        lastTop = r.top;
        v.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setY((float) (r.top / 2.0));
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    items.add("List Item 1");
    items.add("List Item 2");
    items.add("List Item 3");
    items.add("List Item 4");
    items.add("List Item 5");
    items.add("List Item 6");
    items.add("List Item 7");
    items.add("List Item 8");
    items.add("List Item 9");
    items.add("List Item 10");
    items.add("List Item 11");
    items.add("List Item 12");
    items.add("List Item 13");
    items.add("List Item 14");
    items.add("List Item 15");
    items.add("List Item 16");
    items.add("List Item 17");
    items.add("List Item 18");
    items.add("List Item 19");
    items.add("List Item 20");

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);

    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
   /* Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });*/

    //imageview block end


    // image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    listView.addHeaderView(view);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            parallax(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            parallax(imageView);
        }
    });
}
}
```

header.xml

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Load Picture"
        android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Picture"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
```

You should use this

```
Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
```

Because the header is not added into the activity layout yet, so your currently code will get a null pointer when find buttonLoadPicture.

Comment: can you upload the error log after changed? I think you have same issue with this code {this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imgView);}. it's should be {this.imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);}